# @ConfigurationProperties no working when @Autowired on constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have to do @Autowired on the constructor of the Bean to avoid legacy system to break.

Below is the example

```
@Component
public class SampleBean {

@Autowired 
public SampleBean(SampleProperties properties) {
   // use properties 
}
}
```

Here is the SampleProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties 
public class SampleProperties {
    public String hostname;
    //Getter / Setter
}
```

I am using SpringBoot

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class,
        LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        SampleProperties.class
})
public class SampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RioPropertyInitializer.init();
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication, args);
    }
}
```

We are using application.yml file. Here is the problem, When I debug, I can see the hostname value is getting substituted from the application.ml but when it reaches to the constructor hostname is empty.

What can be a problem?

Comment: What is the 'RioPropertyInitializer'? In my small application I got properties autowired.

Comment: Its not working after commenting RioPropertyInitializer. I tried @PostConstruct too but there also I am not getting the properties.

Comment: Can you post properties and describe the application structure? Is it Rest service? If you want I can post sample application which I created to test the problem.

Comment: Your `SampleApplication` needs to be `@Configuration`. Does that help?